# GZipStream doesn't read the whole file

Tags: c#, gzip, filestream, gzipstream

Using GZipStream to open downloaded gzip files and get the xml file inside.

Problem is that sometimes the whole xml file isn't extracted by my code:

```
    private static string Unzip(string fileToUnzip, string format)
    {
        string unzippedFileName = fileToUnzip.Replace(".zip", format);

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileToUnzip);

        using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(unzippedFileName))
                {
                    using (GZipStream Decompress = new GZipStream(inFile,
                            CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
                    {
                        Decompress.CopyTo(outFile);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                int k = 0;
            }
        }

        return unzippedFileName;
    }
```

There is nothing wrong with the gzip files, I can get the xml fil manually using WinRAR.

No exceptions are thrown.

Any ideas for what is going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GZipStream not reading the whole file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068382/gzipstream-not-reading-the-whole-file)

Comment: Nice! Using 7-zip fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using 7-zip fixed the problem.

See [GZipStream not reading the whole file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068382/gzipstream-not-reading-the-whole-file)

Thanks Anders Forsgren!